# Possible to have multiple languages in a single application with routing?

Tags: python, node.js, flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

You can use multiple services in Google App Engine and each service can be in its own language. This is usually done by having different url prefixes, so for example one url is:

- myapp.com/js/*
- myapp.com/python/*

However, I'm wondering if you can mix-and-match endpoints and just set them up with a dispatch file. Here is what I have so far to give an idea of what I'm trying to do:

- default-multi/

  - app.yaml
  - dispatch.yaml
  - js/

    - js.yaml
    - package.json
    - server.js
  - py/

    - py.yaml
    - requirements.txt
    - main.py

And the files are:

`js/js.yaml`

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: js
```

`js/package.json`

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

`js/server.js`

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/js', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Hello, world!').end();
});

app.listen(8080, () => {});
module.exports = app;
```

`py/requirements.txt`

```
Flask==2.1.3
```

`py/py.yaml`

```
runtime: python39
service: py
```

`py/main.py`

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/py')
def hello():
    return jsonify(hello='world')
```

`app.yaml`

```
runtime: python39 # requires I add this ?
service: default
```

`dispatch.yaml`

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/py$"
    service: py

  - url: "*/js$"
    service: js
```

And to dispatch:

```
$ gcloud app deploy app.yaml js/js.yaml py/py.yaml dispatch.yaml
```

Is there an actual way to accomplish what I'm trying to do above, or is it just not possible using GAE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. Here is a working example I have now:

- default_multi/

  - dispatch.yaml

    ```
    dispatch:
      - url: "*/js"
        service: js
      - url: "*/py"
        service: default # 'py'
    ```
  - js/

    - js.yaml

      ```
      runtime: nodejs14
      service: js
      ```
    - package.json

      ```
      {
        "engines": {
            "node": "14.x"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "express": "^4.17.1"
        }
      }
      ```
    - server.js

      ```
      'use strict';
      const express = require('express');
      const app = express();
      app.get('/js', (req, res) => {
         res.status(200).send('Hello, world!').end();
      });

      app.listen(8080, () => {});
      module.exports = app;
      ```
  - py/

    - py.yaml

      ```
      # set this as 'default' yaml
      runtime: python39
      service: default
      ```
    - requirements.txt

      ```
      Flask==2.1.3
      ```
    - main.py

      ```
      from flask import Flask, jsonify

      app = Flask(__name__)
      @app.route('/py')
      def hello():
         return jsonify(hello='world')
      ```

And the command to run it:

```
$ gcloud app deploy py/py.yaml js/js.yaml dispatch.yaml
```

The main points here are that:

- One server needs to be registered as the `default` service, even if the packages are split and equivalent in priority.
- Only the `dispatch.yaml` goes at the top level. This acts as the service-router now.